# Singular solution of $y^2(y - xp) = x^4p^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, singular-solution

Given differential equation, *$y^2(y - xp) = x^4p^2$* where {$p = dy/dx$}

To find the singular solution,

I have extracted the p-discriminant relation which is, *$y^3x^2(y + 4x^2) = 0$*

From here it is evident that all $x = 0, y = 0$ and $y + 4x^2 = 0$ are the singular solutions when tested by putting back in the differential equation but my text book doesn't mention anything about $x=0$ as singular solution. Am I doing any mistake?

Comment: Is $$p=\frac{dy}{dx}$$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I agree with all the comments given by @JJacquelin. I think I arrived at a more simple argument,

While getting the p-discriminant relation of

=> $y^2(y - xp) - x^4p^2 = 0 $

=> $x^4p^2 + xy^2p - y^3 = 0$   {say $Ap^2 + Bp + C = 0$}

then, its p-discriminant relation is $B^2 - 4AC = 0$ {$y^3x^2(y + 4x^2) = 0$} given $A\neq0$ {$x\neq0$}.

So, I think x$=0$ can be directly eliminated here.

Answer (score 2):

$$y^2\left(y - x\frac{dy}{dx}\right) = x^4\left(\frac{dy}{dx}
\right)^2$$
$$y(x)=-4x^2\quad\text{is a singular solution.}$$
$$y(x)=0\quad\text{is a singular solution.}$$
$x(y)=0$ is not solution of the ODE because $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is infinite which doesn't agree with the ODE.

$(x=0, y=0)$ isn't a function but a point. Thus it isn't a solution of the ODE.

The general solution of the ODE is :
$$y(x)=\frac{c^2 x}{x-c}$$
The above singular solutions are the envelope of the general solution.
$$ $$
IN ADDITION, ANSWER TO THE COMMENT from  Hari Prasad (Too long answer to be edited in the comments section) :

The argument raised is :

> When $x=0$ , then $dx/dy =0$ , which means $1/p=0$ , then   $y^2(y/p^2−x/p)−x^4= 0$ when $x=0$  (implicitly $1/p=0$) . So, even $x=0$ is satisfying the differential equation. Is this thinking wrong ?

Let me remind this well-known argument : Given an ODE $$f(x,y,p)=0\tag 1$$ and multiplying by $g(x,y,p)$ gives a different ODE : $$g(x,y,p)f(x,y,p)=0\tag 2$$ which is not equivalent to Eq.$(1)$.The solutions of $(2)$ are the solutions of $(1)$ and the solutions of $(3)$ : $$g(x,y,p)=0\tag 3$$
Thus a solution of $(2)$ is not necessarily a solution of $(1)$. $$ $$ 
In your argument the equation $$f(x,y,p)=y^2(y-xp)-x^4p^2=0\tag 4$$ is multiplied by $g(x,y,p)=\frac{1}{p^2}$. So the solutions of $$y^2(\frac{y}{p^2}-\frac{x}{p})-x^4=0\tag 5$$ are not only the solutions of $(4)$ but in addition the solutions of $$\frac{1}{p^2}=\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2=0\tag 6$$ which are $x(y)=c$ and among them $x(y)=0$.

The solution $x=0$ is solution of $(5)$ but not necessarily solution of $(4)$.

Thus your argument is not correct: It doesn't prove that $x(y)=0$ is solution of Eq.$(4)$.

Comment: When $x = 0$, then $\frac{dx}{dy} =0$, which means $1/p = 0$, then
$y^2(y/p^2 - x/p) - x^4$ = $0$ when $x = 0$ (implicitly $1/p = 0$). So, even $x = 0$ is satisfying the differential equation.
Is this thinking wrong ? 
And what exactly do you mean when you say "doesn't agree with the ODE"

Comment: FIRST : You wrote $\frac{1}{p}=0$. Question : Then what is the value of $p$?. SECOND : You multiply by $\frac{1}{p^2}=0$ the equation $y^2(y-xp)-x^4p^2=0$ in order  to get $y^2(\frac{y}{p^2}-\frac{x}{p})-x^4=0$. Question : How do you justify that multiplying an equation by zero gives an equivalent equation ?

Comment: My above comment is written as a kind of joke. More seriously, see the "Addition" written below my main answer.

Comment: D.E -> $4p^2x(x-a)(x-b) = (3x^2 - 2x(a+b) + ab)^2$  
Gen.Sol -> $c^2 + 2cy + {y^2 - x(x-a)(x-b)} = 0$  
Sing.Sol -> $x = 0, a, b$  
In this case how can you argue $x = 0$ is the singular solution without multiplying with $\frac{1}{p^2}$ ?